# Java Hibernate attributeoverride annotation not working?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Hi I am currently learning Hibernate and I am stuck on a problem where I am trying to override the column name from address to home address and office address. I commented out all office-address code, but the column in database are still "CITY_NAME", "STREET_NAME" and etc.

Could someone please explain this, thanks.

Address.java

```
package org.zm.javabrain.dto;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class Address {
    @Column(name="STREET_NAME")
    private String stree;
    @Column(name="CITY_NAME")
    private String city;
    @Column(name="STATE_NAME")
    private String state;
    @Column(name="ZIP_NAME")
    private String zip;
    public String getStree() {
        return stree;
    }
    public void setStree(String stree) {
        this.stree = stree;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }


}
```

this is UserDetails.java

```
package org.zm.javabrain.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import javax.persistence.AttributeOverrides;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity // change the name of the entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS") // change the name of the table
public class UserDetails implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private Date joinedDate;
    private String description;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(name="HOME_STREET_NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="HOME_CITY_NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="state",column=@Column(name="HOME_STATE_NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="zip",column=@Column(name="HOME_ZIP_NAME"))})   
    private Address homeAddress;

//  @Embedded
//  @AttributeOverrides({
//      @AttributeOverride(name="street",column=@Column(name="OFFICE_STREET_NAME")),
//      @AttributeOverride(name="city",column=@Column(name="OFFICE_CITY_NAME")),
//      @AttributeOverride(name="state",column=@Column(name="OFFICE_STATE_NAME")),
//      @AttributeOverride(name="zip",column=@Column(name="OFFICE_ZIP_NAME"))})
//  private Address officeAddress;
//  
//  public Address getOfficeAddress() {
//      return officeAddress;
//  }
//  public void setOfficeAddress(Address officeAddress) {
//      this.officeAddress = officeAddress;
//  }
    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
    public void setJoinedDate(Date joinedDate) {
        this.joinedDate = joinedDate;
    }

    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }
    public void setHomeAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

This is driver class

```
package org.zm.hibernate;

import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.zm.javabrain.dto.Address;
import org.zm.javabrain.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UserDetails user = new UserDetails();

        Address addr = new Address();
        addr.setCity("chicago");
        addr.setState("IL");
        addr.setStree("Michigen Ave");
        addr.setZip("55414");

        Address officeAddr = new Address();
        officeAddr.setCity("minneapolis");
        officeAddr.setState("Washington Ave");
        officeAddr.setState("MN");
        officeAddr.setZip("55455");

        user.setUsername("11111");
        user.setHomeAddress(addr);
//      user.setOfficeAddress(officeAddr);
        user.setJoinedDate(new Date());
        user.setDescription("this is a description");

        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What hbm2ddl value do you use ?

Comment: @AurelienEcoto here it is <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

Comment: In which file is this property defined? `I commented out all office-address code, but the column in database ...`: have you dropped the old tables before running your code?

Comment: with create-drop the schema should be dropped after the end session Factory. @EricMa Do you see any changes when you modify the name of a table declared using @Column?

Comment: @ujulu that property is defined in hibernate.cfg.xml. Yes, I cleaned the database before I run my program.

Comment: yes, in the Address class I used the Column annotation, and the column in database showed correctly as "STREET_NAME", "CITI_NAME" and etc. I am just not able to override it later in UserDetails class. @AurelienEcoto

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell you if Hibernate `Session` supports the `AttributeOverride` feature or not. The problem is, I guess, Hibernate is mixing two different technologies that are trying to solve the same problem, and that is confusing for new users trying to learn. Hibernate can be used as

- Legacy (Native) ORM , and
- JPA (Java Persistence API) implementation

As I can see from your posted code example that you are using JPA annotations. All annotations, classes and properties having the package structure of `javax.persistence` are JPA specific. So my advice is, either configure your persistence the Hibernate way or the JPA way, and don't mix.

If you want to map your entities the JPA way, do the following:

- Put your configuration information in the file `persistence.xml` instead of in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`. The file should be under `META-INF` folder of your source directory. If you are using Maven put it under `src/main/resources/META-INF` directory. The file should look like:

  ```
  <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
       version="2.1">

      <persistence-unit name="yourPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
          <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
          <class>org.zm.javabrain.dto.UserDetails</class>

          <properties>
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="..." />
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="..." />
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="..." />
              <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="..." />

              <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
              <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
          </properties>

      </persistence-unit>

   </persistence>
  ```

replace the `...` with correct database information.

- In your test class (`HibernateTest`) do the following instead of `SessionFactory / Session`:

  ```
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("yourPU");
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.persist(user);
  em.getTransaction().commit;
  em.close();
  emf.close();
  ```

  You can also read:
- [Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa)
- [Java Persistence API Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm#BNBPY)
- [JPA 2.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1499975406_77e1d7b8515a4b72ff070d9178192b48)

Hopefully, it helps.